# How to make php match regex NOT matching over lines?

Tags: php, regex

My code is

```
preg_replace("/([^; ]+)=>([^; ]+)/", "ec_set('$1',$2);", $input_lines);
```

on matching the following text

```
test=>1; test; test=>123; 

asdf
test=>[[test]]
```

The result

is outputting over-lines

```
ec_set('test',1);; test; ec_set('test',123);; ec_set('

asdf
test',[[test]]);
```

How to make it

```
ec_set('test',1);; test; ec_set('test',123);; 

asdf
ec_set('test',[[test]]);
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([^;\s]+)=>([^;\s]+)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vH0iN5/4

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`preg_replace("/([^;\n ]+)=>([^;\n ]+)/", "ec_set('$1',$2);", $input_lines);`